# 1 = 2? A Non-Math Riddle

Tags: riddle, knowledge

One day, when I was reading a book with my son, he said

> "Hey Dad, this book says that 1 is equal to 2!"

I couldn't figure out what he meant, could you help me? What was my son talking about?

Based off of this puzzle: [3 = 6 ? Another non math question. Another Grandpa Mystery](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70653/3-6-another-non-math-question-another-grandpa-mystery)

Comment: Downvoted for responding to a plausible answer [with a comment like this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70799/1-2-a-non-math-riddle#comment211835_70800).  If an answer solves the puzzle but not in the way you intended, either the question should be updated or the answer marked as accepted.  *Guess what I'm thinking* isn't fun for anyone but you.

Comment: @user1717828 you have a point, but it is fun for me :D

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Could the answer be that

> Today (sounds like two day) is one day? The first two words of the riddle are "one day".

Comment: I think it is ;) +1

Answer (score 4):

I think it's about

> [finger binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger_binary)

where

> the (one) index finger equals the (finger binary) representation of the number 2.

Comment: That would make it a math riddle.

Comment: @Flater but it's a good answer, nonetheless! :D

Answer (score 3):

Could it have anything to do with

> Page numbers and how the cover could be considered the first page or the title page be the first page, but the real start is the second page?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is

> "That one" is equal to 2

Where

> "That one" is a reference a particular something the boy could be looking at such as a math problem, making this an English puzzle. It's used here in the same way, as in "I choose that one" or "that one has spots"

Answer (score 1):

Could the answer have anything to do with the following explanation?

> The boy has a dad. Therefore, the boy must also have a mother. Before the boy was born, the mother was carrying him in her stomach (i.e. she was pregnant). This would be an example of how $1=2$, because although being one person, she is two people (herself and the boy who is yet to be her son). Notice that nothing else is said about the *book* in particular, so that might not be important, assuming this explanation is indeed true.